# Error 400: Redirect_URI_Mismatch from Embed Code Object in Google Sites to Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-sites

I am trying to connect to Google Sheets API from Google Sites using the Embed Code object. It returns the following error when I try to log in:

Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The JavaScript origin in the request, https://xxxxxxxx-atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

OAuth 2.0 Client IDs on Google Cloud Platform do not accept https://googleusercontent.com as the Authorized JavaScript origins, and I'm not sure if there's a way to allow the embed object in Google Sites to access the Google Sheets API.

Please advise.